# Объявление переменной после метки

Tags: c

env.: c11, gcc

Исходный код:

```
#include <sys/types.h>      // system types
#include <sys/stat.h>       // FIFO
#include <fcntl.h>          // O_NONBLOCK
#include <errno.h>          // errno
#include <stdio.h>          // IO
#include <string.h>         // strerror
#include <unistd.h>         // unlink

#define rc_succ (0)
#define rc_fail (-1)
#define no_msg ("")
#define no_flags (0)

#define FULL_RDWR (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH)

const char* fifo_pathname = "/tmp/vbi_flow";
int         fifo_creat_flags = O_NONBLOCK | FULL_RDWR;

int mkfifo_error_resolver(int err);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int        rc;
    const int  buf_size = 1024;
    char       buf[buf_size];

    memset((void*)buf, 0x00, buf_size * sizeof(*buf));

create_fifo:
    // int dummy = 0; // раскомментируйте строку и получите ошибку 
                      // компиляции
    // create FIFO
    if (0 != (rc = mkfifo(fifo_pathname, (mode_t)fifo_creat_flags))) {
        if (rc_succ == mkfifo_error_resolver(errno)) goto create_fifo;
        perror("fifo create");
        return rc_fail;
    }

    printf("FIFO created. Related file: %s\n", fifo_pathname);

    int fifo_fd;
    if (-1 == (fifo_fd = open(fifo_pathname, O_RDWR))) {
        perror("open fifo file");
        goto cancel;
    }

    printf("File %s is open.\n", fifo_pathname);

    int should_cancel = 0;
    while (!should_cancel) {
        //
    }

cancel:
    // close file if exist
    if (fifo_fd > 0) {
        if (0 != (rc = close(fifo_fd)))
            perror("close fifo file");
    }

    // remove file related to FIFO
    if (0 != (rc = unlink(fifo_pathname))) {
        perror("fifo remove");
        return rc_fail;
    }

    printf("FIFO removed.\n");

    return 0;
}

int mkfifo_error_resolver(int err) {
    switch (err) {
        case EEXIST:
            return unlink(fifo_pathname); // unlink returns 0 if success

        default:
            return rc_fail;
    }
}
```

Если сразу под меткой объявить переменную - это приводит к ошибке компиляции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, обратите, пожалуйста, внимание: после метки `create_fifo` можно найти строку кода, в которой объявляется переменная `fifo_fd`. И это не приводит к ошибке компиляции.

Даже если после `create_file` мы вставим `printf(...)`, а уж затем объявим переменную - это все равно приведет к ошибке компиляции.

Comment: Ругается на `write`, которого я не вижу в вашем примере. Приведите самодостаточный код на котором воспроизводится ошибка.

Comment: @zed, извините, счс обновлю скрин

Comment: @zed, код, кстати, самодостаточный.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метку можно привязать только к statement. В языке С (в отличие от С++) объявления не являются statement. К ним нельзя привязать метку.

В данном случае ситуацию спасет `;` сразу после метки

```
create_fifo:;
    int dummy = 0;
```

Это создаст пустой statement, к которому и будет привязана метка.

> Однако, обратите, пожалуйста, внимание: после метки `create_fifo` можно найти строку кода, в которой объявляется переменная `fifo_fd`. И это не приводит к ошибке компиляции.

В самом факте объявления переменной "где-то [далеко] после метки" ничего примечательного нет. Важно именно то, чтобы метка не привязывалась непосредственно к объявлению.

Вышесказанное распространяется и на метки `case` в `switch`.

---

Последствием этого различия является также то, что вот такой код

```
if (1)
  int n = printf("Hello World\n");
```

является корректным с точки зрения С++, но не с точки зрения С.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение @Ant!